# Php query regarding 2 FKs and 1 Primary Key

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys

In my table internships, I have two foreign keys **id_promoter_internship** and **id_supervisor_internship**. In the table business_contacts I have 1 primary key **id_business**. I'm trying to get data from the business_contacts table which is linked to the internships table. Is the following query correct?

```
public function update_form_business_contact($name_enterprise){
    $query = "
        SELECT 
        * 
        FROM business_contacts
            ,internships 
        WHERE 
            business_contacts.id_business = internships.id_supervisor_internship 
            AND internships.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";       
    $result = $this->_db->query($query);

    # Go through results of teachers
    if($result->rowCount()!=0){
        while($row=$result->fetch()){
            $contact= new businesscontact ( $row->id_business,$row->firstname_business,$row->lastname_business,$row->service_business,$row->function_business,$row->phone_business,$row->phone_secretary_business,$row->mobile_business);
        }
    }
    return $contact;
}
```

My question is: Does the primary key have to reference both foreign keys? If so how would I do that.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please post the database tables schema? Since you should use join in your query using inner or left join will differ results based on the way data are stored in your tables. For example is promoter_id equal with supervisor_id in each row?

Comment: Can you please post the database tables schema? In your question `Does the primary key have to reference both foreign keys?` that depends on what you want as result from database, do you want your result to have `id_business=id_promoter_internship=id_supervisor_internship`? In your example you search only one field `id_supervisor_internship`

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a `JOIN` (since that's what a FK is for). The `JOIN` syntax tells the DB how the tables are related (and makes it clear to anyone else working on your code). Incidentally, you should avoid `SELECT *` and list the fields you want.

```
SELECT bc.*, i.* 
FROM 
    business_contacts bc
        INNER JOIN internships i ON bc.id_business = i.id_supervisor_internship 
WHERE 
    i.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'
```

You only need to reference the fields that are relevant. FKs are enforced when you write data in.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get data from `internships`, so *start* with that:

```
SELECT *
FROM internships
```

This gives you the internships themselves, which includes the identifiers for the contacts.  To add information for those contacts, join the table which has that information.  In this case there are two joins, one for each contact:

```
SELECT *
FROM internships
INNER JOIN business_contacts promoter
  ON internships.id_promoter_internship = promoter.id
INNER JOIN business_contacts supervisor
  ON internships.id_supervisor_internship = supervisor.id
```

By giving the table aliases (`promoter` and `supervisor` in this case), you can easily join the same table twice (or as many times as you like, really) and treat it as separate tables.

The result of this would be all of the records in `internships`, and the additional data from `business_contacts` related to each of the keys in the `internships` record.

You can also alias columns so as to make the results more explicit.  Something like:

```
SELECT
    internships.some_field AS some_field,
    promoter.some_field AS promoter_some_field,
    supervisor.some_field AS supervisor_some_field
FROM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so bad but you may want to try this:

```
    <?php

    public function update_form_business_contact($name_enterprise){
        $query = "
                 SELECT
                      *
                 FROM business_contacts bCon
                 INNER JOIN internships  iShip
                 ON bCon.id=iShip.id_supervisor_internship
                 WHERE
                     iShip.name_enterprise_internship = '$name_enterprise'";
        $result = $this->_db->query($query);

        # Go through results of teachers
        if($result->rowCount()!=0){
            while($row=$result->fetch()){
                $contact= new businesscontact ( $row->id_business,$row->firstname_business,$row->lastname_business,$row->service_business,$row->function_business,$row->phone_business,$row->phone_secretary_business,$row->mobile_business);
            }
        }
        return $contact;
    }
```